# Support for Multiple Modal Single Page

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

I'm trying to use some sample code form w3schools.com to include multiple modals on a single page. I've included the code that I'm trying to use below. I got the code from here. http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

Here is an example of the code in action. Note that the first Modal works, but the second Modal does not appear. https://jsfiddle.net/y0uavmo0/

HTML:

```
<h2>Modal Example1</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal1</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..1</p>
  </div>

</div>


<h2>Modal Example2</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal2</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal2-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");


// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are referring both the buttons with same id. So event is only bind for the first button as it is appearing first in the DOM.

If you will change the JS code like below

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName('modal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn");


// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn[0].onclick = function() {
    modal[0].style.display = "block";
}

btn[1].onclick = function() {
    modal[1].style.display = "block";
}
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span[0].onclick = function() {
    modal[0].style.display = "none";
}

span[1].onclick = function() {
    modal[1].style.display = "none";
}
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

and Html code like

```
<h2>Modal Example1</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn" class="myBtn">Open Modal1</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..1</p>
  </div>

</div>


<h2>Modal Example2</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn" class="myBtn">Open Modal2</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal2-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..2</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

This will start working. though you will have some css issues in your modal 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same class for the buttons but you have to use a different id.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName('modal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn");


// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn[0].onclick = function() {
    modal[0].style.display = "block";
}

btn[1].onclick = function() {
    modal[1].style.display = "block";
}
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span[0].onclick = function() {
    modal[0].style.display = "none";
}

span[1].onclick = function() {
    modal[1].style.display = "none";
}
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h2>Modal Example1</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn" class="myBtn">Open Modal1</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..1</p>
  </div>

</div>


<h2>Modal Example2</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn2" class="myBtn">Open Modal2</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..2</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I copied and text the exact same code in my text editor, tried to run it, it doesn't work. I wonder why?