# Creating Multiple Modals on a Single Page

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

I'm having some issues creating multiple modals on a single webpage following the sample code from w3schools.com. The code in question that I am using is this one: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal2

I found a similar topic on the problem however after trying that solution in jsfiddle I still came up with no result, does anyone have any ideas?

Previous Topic:
[Support for Multiple Modal Single Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37402241/support-for-multiple-modal-single-page)

https://jsfiddle.net/oa1dr3q6/

```
<h2>1st Modal</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<span class="close">×</span>
<h2>Modal Header</h2>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
<p>Some other text...</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<h3>Modal Footer</h3>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<h2>2nd Modal</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<span class="close">×</span>
<h2>Modal Header</h2>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
<p>Some other text...</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<h3>Modal Footer</h3>
</div>
```

Script:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Support for Multiple Modal Single Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37402241/support-for-multiple-modal-single-page)

Comment: Take a look at the answer of the question you linked to. It will solve your problem.

Comment: I did and I am having trouble getting it to work, maybe I'm missing something? I updated the jsfiddle using the solution from the topic
https://jsfiddle.net/oa1dr3q6/6/

Comment: Your code is almost exactly the same as the ***question*** code. Read the answer below it. There is extra Javascript in the answer below. Add that, and it will work.

Comment: I looked at the answer and copied it completely and still have no luck.

Comment: On your JSFiddle, use `class="myBtn"` instead of `id="myBtn"` then it should work.

Comment: Amazing, that absolutely solved. Thank you for the help, sorry for dealing with my novice errors! I do have one more question if you don't mind.

Comment: What is your other question? Also, I will post my solution as an answer, and if you click the green checkmark next to the answer, it will mark it as correct.

Comment: I plan on implementing a modal to a total of 6 elements on my page, how do I revise the javascript to accommodate that? Would it be adding addition btn[1].onclick = function() { modal[1].style.display = "block"; } and span[1].onclick = function() { modal[1].style.display = "none"; } With the numbers correlating to the next number for the next modal?

Comment: Basically, it creates an array of items, so you would increment the number each time, but an array starts at zero, so the first modal would be [0], like you already have, and the second would be [1] (which you also already have). After that, you just repeat the lines of code, replacing [1] with [2], [3], [4], and [5]

Comment: Alright, awesome! Thank again for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your JSFiddle, make sure you use `class="myBtn"` instead of `id="myBtn"` then it should work.

Here is the full working code:

**HTML:**

```
<h2>1st Modal</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button class="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<h2>2nd Modal</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button class="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal2-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**JS:**

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName('modal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn");


// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn[0].onclick = function() {
    modal[0].style.display = "block";
}

btn[1].onclick = function() {
    modal[1].style.display = "block";
}
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span[0].onclick = function() {
    modal[0].style.display = "none";
}

span[1].onclick = function() {
    modal[1].style.display = "none";
}
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal[0]) {
         modal[0].style.display = "none";
     }
    if (event.target == modal[1]) {
         modal[1].style.display = "none";
     }  
}
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly! Great job, I'd been stuck on this for a good while.

Comment: Since, this answer is at top, Don't forget to modify the window.onclick to reflect modals. Will try to modify the answer.

Comment: What is the `[0]` and `[1]` used for? I don’t get it… and what if we would have more than two modals?

Answer (score 11):

- You assigned the same Id to both modal triggering buttons. Different elements shouldn't have the same Id.
- In you JavaScript code, you always pick a single element (a single close button, a single open button, etc).

It's a HTML/JS beginner's mistake I would say. This would work:

```js
// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.querySelectorAll("button.modal-button");

// All page modals
var modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
 btn[i].onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    modal = document.querySelector(e.target.getAttribute("href"));
    modal.style.display = "block";
 }
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
 spans[i].onclick = function() {
    for (var index in modals) {
      if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined') modals[index].style.display = "none";    
    }
 }
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('modal')) {
     for (var index in modals) {
      if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined') modals[index].style.display = "none";    
     }
    }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<h2>1st Modal</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button class="modal-button" href="#myModal1">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<h2>2nd Modal</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button class="modal-button" href="#myModal2">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I did already get a solution however I am interesting in learning how your javascript solution works. I was going to add a new line in the javascript for each modal I planned on adding however does your solution account for as many modals as I need without having to add additional lines? Sorry if my question is confusing.

Comment: @ccruz yes, it will work for any number of modals. that's how it's usually done :) so when you add a new modal - just add a unique ID to that element, and then add a button somewhere that has the same unique ID in "href" attribute

Comment: @ccruz which solution did you find?

Comment: @Denis Mysenko  Hello. Tell me how to translate your code to <a href instead of button  <a href="#myModal1" class="modal-button">Open modal</a> not work.  thanks.

Comment: @Denis Mysenko with href figured out. Tell me please.I using your code. I have many of these modal windows. There is a table of 100+ positions. If I scroll the page to the end and call the dialog, then the page goes back to the beginning and the dialog is called. How can I make the page not go back to the beginning?  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Some improvements based on @junkfoodjunkie's answer

Popup / modal in html and CSS without JS :

```css
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #012766;
    background: #012766;
    padding: 10px 16px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
[id^=modal] {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
[id^=modal]:target {
    display: block;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
}
.popup {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 99999;
}
.popup__overlay {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000000b3;
}
.popup__wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 58px 32px 32px 32px;
    background: #fff;
}
.popup__close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    right: 26px;
}
```

```html
<a class="button" href="#modal1">Open modal 1</a>

<div class="popup" id="modal1">
    <a class="popup__overlay" href="#"></a>
    <div class="popup__wrapper">
        <a class="popup__close" href="#">Close icon here</a>
        <p>POPUP 1 : CONTENT HERE</p>
    </div>
</div>


<a class="button" href="#modal2">Open modal 2</a>

<div class="popup" id="modal2">
    <a class="popup__overlay" href="#"></a>
    <div class="popup__wrapper">
        <a class="popup__close" href="#">Close icon here</a>
        <p>POPUP 2 : CONTENT HERE</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using so much code, and javascript to do something you can do using just CSS and HTML? (simplified example, animations and such can of course be added)

```css
[id^=modal] {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  min-height: 3em;
  min-width: 5em;
  max-width: 10em;
  }
input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  }
#modal1:target {
  display: block;
  }
#modal2:target {
  display: block;
  }
[id^=modal] a {
  float: right;
  }
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <p>This is the content-container</p>
    <a href="#modal1">Open first modal</a><br>
    <a href="#modal2">Open second modal</a>
  <div id="modal1"><a href="#">Close</a>This is the first modal</div>
  <div id="modal2"><a href="#">Close</a>This is the second modal</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is awesome. I thought modals without some kind of JS were impossible, this is so clean.

Comment: If you use Bootstrap 4.5, you won't need any additional CSS or Javascript, pure HTML.

Comment: If the modals are being filled with data from AJAX calls it needs JS.

Answer (score 2):

I Know i'm late.

Check this out.

```css
 body {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }

        /* The Modal (background) */
        .modal {
            display: none;
            /* Hidden by default */
            position: fixed;
            /* Stay in place */
            z-index: 1;
            /* Sit on top */
            padding-top: 80px;
            /* Location of the box */
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            /* Full width */
            height: 100%;
            /* Full height */
            overflow: auto;
            /* Enable scroll if needed */
            background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            /* Fallback color */
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
            /* Black w/ opacity */
            overflow: auto;
        }

        /* Modal Content */
        .modal-content {
            max-height: 80%;
            overflow: auto;
            position: relative;
            background-color: #fefefe;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 0;
            border: 1px solid #888;
            width: 80%;
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
            -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
            animation-name: animatetop;
            animation-duration: 0.4s
        }

        /* Add Animation */
        @-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
            from {
                top: -300px;
                opacity: 0
            }

            to {
                top: 0;
                opacity: 1
            }
        }

        @keyframes animatetop {
            from {
                top: -300px;
                opacity: 0
            }

            to {
                top: 0;
                opacity: 1
            }
        }

        /* The Close Button */
        .close {
            color: white;
            float: right;
            font-size: 28px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .close:hover,
        .close:focus {
            color: #000;
            text-decoration: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .modal-header {
            padding: 2px 16px;
            background-color: #5cb85c;
            color: white;
        }

        .modal-body {
            padding: 2px 16px;
        }

        .modal-footer {
            padding: 2px 16px;
            background-color: #5cb85c;
            color: white;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="modal.css">
</head>

<body>
    <button id="myBtn">Button 1</button>
    <button id="myBtn1">Button 2</button>
    <button id="myBtn2">Button 3</button>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">

        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <span class="close">&times;</span>
                <h2>Button 1 Clicked</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus aspernatur perferendis ad sunt.
                    Eius, possimus? Quae at eum repudiandae obcaecati vitae accusantium, perferendis sapiente
                    temporibus, necessitatibus voluptatem iste cumque et?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal1" class="modal">

        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <span class="close">&times;</span>
                <h2>Button 2 Clicked</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores voluptatum ipsa cum aliquid, ex
                    inventore, culpa obcaecati modi deleniti enim consequuntur tenetur. Earum numquam sit ratione eum
                    sequi praesentium, unde maxime ullam iure rem mollitia perferendis eos possimus neque, nisi dicta.
                    Obcaecati dignissimos, dolores labore rerum quisquam non explicabo repellat!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal2" class="modal">

        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <span class="close">&times;</span>
                <h2>Button 3 Clicked</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit laudantium quia non laborum
                    ea, similique ex iusto minus obcaecati optio sapiente aut eveniet porro odio veniam excepturi
                    facilis iste fuga? Porro atque odio, fuga blanditiis voluptate ducimus veritatis id ea possimus?
                    Facilis tempore officiis quos assumenda dolorem placeat sed veniam dolor eveniet magnam. Iure ullam
                    odit qui, magni suscipit pariatur nesciunt temporibus aspernatur doloribus quis nobis quas esse
                    perspiciatis, asperiores eum quidem placeat minus alias veniam molestias sit. Ipsam numquam,
                    sapiente facere voluptatem eum, maiores blanditiis cupiditate corporis quos ratione, quia
                    praesentium dolore nihil voluptatum impedit quae consequatur sit pariatur.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script>
        var datamap = new Map([
            [document.getElementById("myBtn"), document.getElementById("myModal")],
            [document.getElementById("myBtn1"), document.getElementById("myModal1")],
            [document.getElementById("myBtn2"), document.getElementById("myModal2")]
        ]);

        datamap.forEach((value, key) => {
            doModal(key, value);
        });

        function doModal(anchor, popupbox) {

            // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
            var span = popupbox.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

            anchor.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                popupbox.style.display = "block";
            });

            span.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                popupbox.style.display = "none";
            });

            window.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                if (event.target == popupbox) {
                    popupbox.style.display = "none";
                }
            });
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Just keep adding the entry in MAP for every popup you create.
in Map

1. 1st Parameter
   Element which is used to display popup. (in out case it's buttons)
2. 2nd Parameter
   Modal Popup window itself

Answer (score 2):

---

My proposal

```
const btns = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
const spans = document.getElementsByClassName('close');
const modals = document.getElementsByClassName('modal');

[...btns].forEach((btn, ind) => {
  btn.onclick = () => (modals[ind].style.display = 'block');
});

[...spans].forEach((span, ind) => {
  span.onclick = () => (modals[ind].style.display = 'none');
});

window.onclick = (e) => {
  [...modals].forEach((modal) => {
    if (e.target === modal) {
      modal.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
};
```

If your will not use ID but just classnames
instead of

```
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">

<span class="close">×</span>
```

just use

```html
<button class="btn">Open Modal</button>

<div class="modal">

<span class="close">x</span>
```

You can store all opening buttons within HTML collection

```js
const btns = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
```

Transfer HTML collection to an array

```
[...btns]
```

Add onclick event to each button within array

```
.forEach((btn, ind) => {
  btn.onclick = () => (modals[ind].style.display = 'block');
});
```

You do the same thing for span (closing button)

Comment: What is this ? No information, nothing ... ?

Comment: @PanDe Sorry yep added the short description

Answer (score 1):

I know there are many answers on here, but I wanted to share what I ended up coming up with. My solution is based off of passing an id into a function that corresponds to each modal.

In the below example I use two modals, but you can use more. You just set the id in the `modal` class elements and pass the same id to the `button` `openModal` function in the `onclick`.

```js
var modals = document.getElementsByClassName("modal");
var modalOpenBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("modalOpenBtn");
var currentModal = null;

// Function to open modal by id
function openModal(id) {
  for (i = 0; i < modals.length; i++) {
    if (modals[i].getAttribute('id') == id) {
      currentModal = modals[i];
      currentModal.style.display = "block";
      break;
    }
  }
}

// When the user clicks the button, open modal with the same id
modalOpenBtn.onclick = function() {
  let currentID = modalOpenBtn.getAttribute('id');
  openModal(currentID);
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal or the X, close
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == currentModal || event.target.getAttribute('class') == 'modalClose') {
    currentModal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  }

  .modalContent {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 40%;
    max-width: 450px;
  }

  .modalClose {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .modalClose:hover,
  .modalClose:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<!-- Two modals here, but could use more, just update ids on the modal class elements and in the buttons onclick openModal() call. -->

<button id="modalA" class="modalOpenBtn" onclick="openModal('modalA')">Modal A</button>
  <div id="modalA" class="modal">
    <div class="modalContent">
      <span class="modalClose">×</span>
      <div>
        Modal A text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button id="modalB" class="modalOpenBtn" onclick="openModal('modalB')">Modal B</button>
  <div id="modalB" class="modal">
    <div class="modalContent">
      <span class="modalClose">×</span>
      <div>
        Modal B text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have the same ids added in each `openModalBtn` class elements because you could `getAttribute` the id from the clicked button instead of passing it in the function.

Answer (score 0):

An update on the excellent answer given by [Denis Mysenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4675269/denis-mysenko):

My JS used to be (for one modal):

```js
let modal = document.getElementById('about-modal');
let btn = document.getElementById('about-modal-btn');
let close = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = 'block';
}

close.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

window.onkeydown = function(event) {
    if (event.key == 'Escape') {
        modal.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

My new JS (adopted from Denis's answer:

```js
let modals = document.getElementsByClassName('modal');
let modalBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('modal-btn');
let closeBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('close');

for(let modalBtn of modalBtns) {
    modalBtn.onclick = function(event) {
        document.querySelector(event.target.getAttribute('href') ).style.display = 'block';
    }
}

for(let closeBtn of closeBtns) {
    closeBtn.onclick = function(event) {
        event.target.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if(event.target.classList.contains('modal') ) {
        for(let modal of modals) {
            if(typeof modal.style !== 'undefined') {
                modal.style.display = 'none';    
            }
        }
    }
}

window.onkeydown = function(event) {
    if (event.key == 'Escape') {
        for(let modal of modals) {
            modal.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps someone else in the future. I cleaned up some inconsistencies and other minor things and simplified the code and variable names, using es6 syntax, etc. Someone can also probably make use of the code for a single modal. Sample modal structure:

```html
<button id="settings-modal-btn" class="modal-btn" href="#settings-modal">Settings</button>
<div id="settings-modal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <button class="close">&times;</button>
        <p>Content here...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```