# Modal Window won't close

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

This is a follow up issue I am having from my previous topic
[Creating Multiple Modals on a Single Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40645032/creating-multiple-modals-on-a-single-page)

In the following suggestions they all worked perfectly and I was under the assumption I could make the modal work on an image opposed to a button element however that doesn't seem to be the case. I can open the modal perfectly fine however the × won't trigger the close of the modal and I can't figure out why. I disabled all my CSS that was attached to my page with the assumption something was interfering with it however I fun into the same result so I have reason to believe the problem is within the javascript? Would anyone have any ideas how to solve it? Thanks.

```js
// Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementsByClassName('modal');

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn");


    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
    btn[0].onclick = function() {
    modal[0].style.display = "block";
    }

    btn[1].onclick = function() {
    modal[1].style.display = "block";
    }
    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span[0].onclick = function() {
    modal[0].style.display = "none";
    }

    span[1].onclick = function() {
    modal[1].style.display = "none";
    }
    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    }
    }
```

```html
<div class="four columns">
    <div class="myBtn">
    <figure class="effect-zoe">
    <img src="images/sample-1.jpg" alt="img25"/>
    <figcaption>
    <h2>Kinetic Kids Rebrand</h2>
    <p class="description">Zoe never had the patience of her sisters. She deliberately punched the bear in his face.</p>
    </figcaption>   
    </figure>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">

     <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
     <span class="close">×</span>
     <h2>Project 1</h2>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
     <img src="images/sample-1.jpg" alt="img25"/>
     <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
     <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
               
              
    <div class="four columns">
    <div class="myBtn">
    <figure class="effect-zoe">
    <img src="images/sample-1.jpg" alt="img25"/>
    <figcaption>
     
     <h2>Cyber Block App</h2>
    <p class="description">Zoe never had the patience of her sisters. She deliberately punched the bear in his face.</p>
    </figcaption>   
    </figure> 

     <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal2" class="modal">

     <!-- Modal content -->
     <div class="modal2-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <h2>Project 2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
    <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Check this link:-http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal

Comment: I'm afraid I can't make sense of the answer from here, I used their examples for the base of my modals and they work perfectly fine when applied to a button however when I try to attack it to an image the modal won't close after being opened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your span that closes the modal is inside of the div that is the "button" that opens the modal.

When the click event fires on the span, it also fires on the parent div. So the modal is instantly hidden and then re-shown.

To fix this, just make sure that you separate the div for the button from the div for the modal:

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName('modal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn");


// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn[0].onclick = function() {
modal[0].style.display = "block";
}

btn[1].onclick = function() {
modal[1].style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span[0].onclick = function() {
modal[0].style.display = "none";
}

span[1].onclick = function() {
modal[1].style.display = "none";
}
    
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

```html
<div class="four columns">
<div class="myBtn">
    <figure class="effect-zoe">
        <img src="images/sample-1.jpg" alt="img25" />
        <figcaption>
            <h2>Kinetic Kids Rebrand</h2>
            <p class="description">Zoe never had the patience of her sisters. She deliberately punched the bear in his face.</p>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <span class="close">×</span>
            <h2>Project 1</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <img src="images/sample-1.jpg" alt="img25" />
            <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
            <p>Some other text...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="four columns">
<div class="myBtn">
    <figure class="effect-zoe">
        <img src="images/sample-1.jpg" alt="img25" />
        <figcaption>
            <h2>Cyber Block App</h2>
            <p class="description">Zoe never had the patience of her sisters. She deliberately punched the bear in his face.</p>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal2-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <span class="close">×</span>
            <h2>Project 2</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
            <p>Some other text...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, sorry for the delayed response. Your solution worked perfectly, thank you very much!