# Javascript, target data without knowing the element name

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to target a modal, without an id or class. This is because my team page is controlled by a CMS, and hence each time a team member is added, each one will have a different `data-modal="NAME-I-WILL-NOT-KNOW"`

My CMS is controlling the `"NAME-I-WILL-NOT-KNOW"` part of this code.

Example: a client creates a new team member called "Bob Smith". Hence my HTML will result in:

Button

```
  <div class="button-wrap">
    <a rel="modal:open" class="button is-danger is-rounded modal-button" data-modal-target="bobsmith" aria-haspopup="true">
      <span>View Profile</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Modal

```
  <div id="modalopen" class="modal" data-modal="bobsmith">
  </div>
```

I thought I might be able to target with a `document.querySelector` of some sort. I've tried a few methods, but the following feels the closest.

```
var modal = document.querySelector("[data-modal=" + target + "]");
```

Although, needless to say, this isn't working.

I've created this without the cms elements for obvious reasons.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.querySelector("[data-modal=" + target + "]");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("modal_open");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.team {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2.375em;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.team img {
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 0;
}

.team h3 {
  color: #00315c;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.45;
  margin: 1rem 0 0 0;
}

.team h5 {
  color: #b5b5b5;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1.45;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.team p {
  color: #4a4a4a;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.45;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.team .button-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.team .social li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0.875rem;
}

.team .social li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0rem;
}

.team-button-wrap {
  margin-top: 1.15rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.home-team-intro .button-wrap {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px),
print {
  .modal-content {
    width: 753px;
    height: auto;
  }
}

.modal-background {
  background-color: rgba(18, 18, 18, 0.68);
}

.team-card-full {
  background-color: white;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 2.375em;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px),
print {
  .team-card-full {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}

.team-card-full p {
  text-align: left;
}

.team-card-full .profile {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.team-card-full .profile img {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="hero is-medium">
  <div class="hero-body">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="columns">
        <!-- CARD 1 PREVIEW START -->
        <div class="column">
          <div class="card team">
            <div class="card-head">
              <img class="obj_fit" src="#">
              <h3>Foo 1</h3>
              <h5>Position</h5>
            </div>
            <p>Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.</p>
            <div class="button-wrap">
              <a id="modal_open" class="button is-danger is-rounded modal-button" data-modal-target="foo1" aria-haspopup="true">
                <span>View Profile</span>
              </a>
            </div>
            <!-- MODAL START -->
            <div id="modal" class="modal" data-modal="foo1">
              <div class="modal-background"></div>
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="team-card-full">
                  <div class="column is-12-mobile is-4-tablet profile">
                    <img src="#">
                    <h3>Foo 1</h3>
                    <h5>Position</h5>
                    <div class="social">
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="mailto:#" target="_blank"><i class="fal fa-envelope-open"></i></a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="column is-12-mobile is-8-tablet">
                    <div class="content">
                      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>
                      <p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <button class="modal-close is-large animated fadeIn" aria-label="close"></button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- MODAL END -->
            <div class="social">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="mailto:#" target="_blank"><i class="fal fa-envelope-open"></i></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- CARD 1 PREVIEWEND -->
        <!-- CARD 1 PREVIEW START -->
        <div class="column">
          <div class="card team">
            <div class="card-head">
              <img class="obj_fit" src="#">
              <h3>Foo 2</h3>
              <h5>Position</h5>
            </div>
            <p>Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.</p>
            <div class="button-wrap">
              <a id="modal_open" class="button is-danger is-rounded modal-button" data-modal-target="foo2" aria-haspopup="true">
                <span>View Profile</span>
              </a>
            </div>
            <!-- MODAL START -->
            <div id="modal" class="modal" data-modal="foo2">
              <div class="modal-background"></div>
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="team-card-full">
                  <div class="column is-12-mobile is-4-tablet profile">
                    <img src="#">
                    <h3>Foo 2</h3>
                    <h5>Position</h5>
                    <div class="social">
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="mailto:#" target="_blank"><i class="fal fa-envelope-open"></i></a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="column is-12-mobile is-8-tablet">
                    <div class="content">
                      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>
                      <p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <button class="modal-close is-large animated fadeIn" aria-label="close"></button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- MODAL END -->
            <div class="social">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="mailto:#" target="_blank"><i class="fal fa-envelope-open"></i></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- CARD 1 PREVIEWEND -->
        <!-- CARD 1 PREVIEW START -->
        <div class="column">
          <div class="card team">
            <div class="card-head">
              <img class="obj_fit" src="#">
              <h3>Foo 3</h3>
              <h5>Position</h5>
            </div>
            <p>Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.</p>
            <div class="button-wrap">
              <a id="modal_open" class="button is-danger is-rounded modal-button" data-modal-target="foo3" aria-haspopup="true">
                <span>View Profile</span>
              </a>
            </div>
            <!-- MODAL START -->
            <div id="modal" class="modal" data-modal="foo3">
              <div class="modal-background"></div>
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="team-card-full">
                  <div class="column is-12-mobile is-4-tablet profile">
                    <img src="#">
                    <h3>Foo 3</h3>
                    <h5>Position</h5>
                    <div class="social">
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="mailto:#" target="_blank"><i class="fal fa-envelope-open"></i></a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="column is-12-mobile is-8-tablet">
                    <div class="content">
                      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>
                      <p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <button class="modal-close is-large animated fadeIn" aria-label="close"></button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- MODAL END -->
            <div class="social">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="mailto:#" target="_blank"><i class="fal fa-envelope-open"></i></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- CARD 1 PREVIEWEND -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: So after the modal is created then it has an id/class that was generated by the CMS?

Comment: Where is the js variable `target`that you use in your modal query defined?

Comment: `var target = "foo2"` logs the elements correctly in your pen.

Comment: @Jacob The cms is adding a string value to `data-modal-target="string"` and data-modal="string" for them to match. However, I will never know the result of that string.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector('[data-modal]');
```

will [select the first element that *has* a `data-modal` attribute](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#attribute-representation), no matter its value.

Answer (score 0):

you could take advantage of the `btn.onclick` event to define your modal:

```
btn.onclick = function openModal(event) {

    var target = this.dataset.modalTarget
  // Get the modal
    modal = document.querySelector("[data-modal=" + target + "]");
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

You should also define your `modal` var first, and add some guards in other listeners using `modal`. The snippet below is a way to correct yours:

```js
var modal = undefined
// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("modal_open");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function openModal(event) {
 
 var target = this.dataset.modalTarget
  // Get the modal
  modal = document.querySelector("[data-modal=" + target + "]");
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  if (modal === undefined) return

  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (modal === undefined) return

  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.team {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2.375em;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.team img {
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 0;
}

.team h3 {
  color: #00315c;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.45;
  margin: 1rem 0 0 0;
}

.team h5 {
  color: #b5b5b5;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1.45;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.team p {
  color: #4a4a4a;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.45;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.team .button-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.team .social li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0.875rem;
}

.team .social li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0rem;
}

.team-button-wrap {
  margin-top: 1.15rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.home-team-intro .button-wrap {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px),
print {
  .modal-content {
    width: 753px;
    height: auto;
  }
}

.modal-background {
  background-color: rgba(18, 18, 18, 0.68);
}

.team-card-full {
  background-color: white;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 2.375em;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px),
print {
  .team-card-full {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}

.team-card-full p {
  text-align: left;
}

.team-card-full .profile {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.team-card-full .profile img {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="hero is-medium">
  <div class="hero-body">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="columns">
        <!-- CARD 1 PREVIEW START -->
        <div class="column">
          <div class="card team">
            <div class="card-head">
              <img class="obj_fit" src="#">
              <h3>Foo 1</h3>
              <h5>Position</h5>
            </div>
            <p>Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.</p>
            <div class="button-wrap">
              <a id="modal_open" class="button is-danger is-rounded modal-button" data-modal-target="foo1" aria-haspopup="true">
                <span>View Profile</span>
              </a>
            </div>
            <!-- MODAL START -->
            <div id="modal" class="modal" data-modal="foo1">
              <div class="modal-background"></div>
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="team-card-full">
                  <div class="column is-12-mobile is-4-tablet profile">
                    <img src="#">
                    <h3>Foo 1</h3>
                    <h5>Position</h5>
                    <div class="social">
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="mailto:#" target="_blank"><i class="fal fa-envelope-open"></i></a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="column is-12-mobile is-8-tablet">
                    <div class="content">
                      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>
                      <p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <button class="modal-close is-large animated fadeIn" aria-label="close"></button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- MODAL END -->
            <div class="social">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="mailto:#" target="_blank"><i class="fal fa-envelope-open"></i></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- CARD 1 PREVIEWEND -->
        <!-- CARD 1 PREVIEW START -->
        <div class="column">
          <div class="card team">
            <div class="card-head">
              <img class="obj_fit" src="#">
              <h3>Foo 2</h3>
              <h5>Position</h5>
            </div>
            <p>Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.</p>
            <div class="button-wrap">
              <a id="modal_open" class="button is-danger is-rounded modal-button" data-modal-target="foo2" aria-haspopup="true">
                <span>View Profile</span>
              </a>
            </div>
            <!-- MODAL START -->
            <div id="modal" class="modal" data-modal="foo2">
              <div class="modal-background"></div>
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="team-card-full">
                  <div class="column is-12-mobile is-4-tablet profile">
                    <img src="#">
                    <h3>Foo 2</h3>
                    <h5>Position</h5>
                    <div class="social">
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="mailto:#" target="_blank"><i class="fal fa-envelope-open"></i></a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="column is-12-mobile is-8-tablet">
                    <div class="content">
                      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>
                      <p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <button class="modal-close is-large animated fadeIn" aria-label="close"></button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- MODAL END -->
            <div class="social">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="mailto:#" target="_blank"><i class="fal fa-envelope-open"></i></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- CARD 1 PREVIEWEND -->
        <!-- CARD 1 PREVIEW START -->
        <div class="column">
          <div class="card team">
            <div class="card-head">
              <img class="obj_fit" src="#">
              <h3>Foo 3</h3>
              <h5>Position</h5>
            </div>
            <p>Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.</p>
            <div class="button-wrap">
              <a id="modal_open" class="button is-danger is-rounded modal-button" data-modal-target="foo3" aria-haspopup="true">
                <span>View Profile</span>
              </a>
            </div>
            <!-- MODAL START -->
            <div id="modal" class="modal" data-modal="foo3">
              <div class="modal-background"></div>
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="team-card-full">
                  <div class="column is-12-mobile is-4-tablet profile">
                    <img src="#">
                    <h3>Foo 3</h3>
                    <h5>Position</h5>
                    <div class="social">
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="mailto:#" target="_blank"><i class="fal fa-envelope-open"></i></a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="column is-12-mobile is-8-tablet">
                    <div class="content">
                      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>
                      <p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <button class="modal-close is-large animated fadeIn" aria-label="close"></button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- MODAL END -->
            <div class="social">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="mailto:#" target="_blank"><i class="fal fa-envelope-open"></i></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- CARD 1 PREVIEWEND -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

There may be a better solution suitable to your problem depending on how and if your CMS is describing the variable `target`. And you could apply the solution above to all of your buttons at the same time, using `document.querySelectorAll('[data-modal-target]')` which will return a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/NodeList) contaning all your buttons. Then you can iterate over it.

Comment: This is great, however, the second and third models do not work? Which I think you may have answered, however, I am not understanding the answer correctly

Comment: The issue is that your question has many issues that cannot be all accorded. [so] is more focused on Q&A about a specific and unique issue, that can be reproduced by a [mcve]. You should, IMHO, open another question if you still have issues. I've tried my best in this answer to give you both a solution for the issue you pointed the most in your question, and hints for further improvements. I've also said that my answer is _a way_ to fix your issue because it is too broad to have a single solution (hence the downvotes I think). I won't implement a complete solution for you, that is your task :)

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I really appreciate your effort and patience. I agree it is not for you to answer all my issues. I was just trying to understand the information you had provided.

Answer (score -1):

You're missing some quotes. The format is `"[data-modal='bobsmith']"`. Try this:

```
var modal = document.querySelector("[data-modal='" + target + "']");
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for everyone's help. The answers you provided led me to another question which led to an overall answer.

Please see [Denis Mysenko answer on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40645032/creating-multiple-modals-on-a-single-page)

Comment: This is not an answer by any mean... You really should look into creating questions and answer that may be useful to other persons in the future, and insert the real content of the answer in here, to avoid link rot... (link that may not exist later on)