# Problem with closing a modal in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

Im currently working on a html-page where I have used several modals on a single page. The basic outline for the modal code is https://stackoverflow.com/a/40645204 . I dont have any problem when I just use this code.
When I have added a grid to make sure the placement of the diffrent modals is okay I suddenly am unable to Close the modals.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName('modal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn");


// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn[0].onclick = function () {
    modal[0].style.display = "block";
}

btn[1].onclick = function () {
    modal[1].style.display = "block";
}

btn[2].onclick = function () {
    modal[2].style.display = "block";
}

btn[3].onclick = function () {
    modal[3].style.display = "block";
}

btn[4].onclick = function () {
    modal[4].style.display = "block";
}

btn[5].onclick = function () {
    modal[5].style.display = "block";
}

btn[6].onclick = function () {
    modal[6].style.display = "block";
}

btn[7].onclick = function () {
    modal[8].style.display = "block";
}

btn[9].onclick = function () {
    modal[9].style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span[0].onclick = function () {
    modal[0].style.display = "none";
}

span[1].onclick = function () {
    modal[1].style.display = "none";
}

span[2].onclick = function () {
    modal[2].style.display = "none";
}

span[3].onclick = function () {
    modal[3].style.display = "none";
}

span[4].onclick = function () {
    modal[4].style.display = "none";
}

span[5].onclick = function () {
    modal[5].style.display = "none";
}

span[6].onclick = function () {
    modal[6].style.display = "none";
}

span[7].onclick = function () {
    modal[7].style.display = "none";
}

span[8].onclick = function () {
    modal[8].style.display = "none";
}

span[9].onclick = function () {
    modal[9].style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: left;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

    .close:hover,
    .close:focus {
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    border: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

.grid-container2 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.13);
    padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item2 {
    background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.13);
    background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
    border: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.13);
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="sv-se">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Artister</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/modalcss.css">
   </head>
<body>

    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-item">
            <h2>Modal Example1</h2>

            <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
            <button id="myBtn" class="myBtn"><img src="img/bandlogos/Rammsteinlogo.png" alt="Rammsteins logga" width="300" height="200" /></button>

            <!-- The Modal -->
            <div id="myModal" class="modal">

                <!-- Modal content -->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <span class="close">×</span>
                    <p>Some text in the Modal..1</p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item">
            <h2>Modal Example2</h2>

            <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
            <button id="myBtn2" class="myBtn"><img src="img/bandlogos/Toollogo.png" alt="Tools logga" width="300" height="200" /></button>

            <!-- The Modal -->
            <div id="myModal2" class="modal">

                <!-- Modal content -->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <span class="close">×</span>
                    <p>Some text in the Modal..2</p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item">
          
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item">
            <h2>Modal Example2</h2>

            <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
            <button id="myBtn4" class="myBtn">><img src="img/bandlogos/Defleppardlogo.jpg" alt="Def Leppards logga" width="300" height="200" /></button>

            <!-- The Modal -->
            <div id="myModal4" class="modal">

                <!-- Modal content -->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <span class="close">×</span>
                    <p>Some text in the Modal..2</p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item">
            <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
            <button id="myBtn3" class="myBtn"><img src="img/bandlogos/alicecooperlogo.png" alt="Alice Coopers logga" width="300" height="200" /></button>

            <!-- The Modal -->
            <div id="myModal2" class="modal">

                <!-- Modal content -->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <span class="close">×</span>
                    <p>Some text in the Modal..2</p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="grid-item">
            <h2>Modal Example2</h2>

            <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
            <button id="myBtn6" class="myBtn"><img src="img/bandlogos/Hardcoresuperstarlogo.jpeg" alt="Hardcore Superstars logga" width="300" height="200" /></button>

            <!-- The Modal -->
            <div id="myModal2" class="modal">

                <!-- Modal content -->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <span class="close">×</span>
                    <p>Some text in the Modal..2</p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item">
            <h2>Modal Example2</h2>

            <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
            <button id="myBtn2" class="myBtn"><img src="img/bandlogos/Lifeloverlogo.png" alt="Lifelovers logga" width="300" height="200" /></button>

            <!-- The Modal -->
            <div id="myModal2" class="modal">

                <!-- Modal content -->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <span class="close">×</span>
                    <p>Some text in the Modal..2</p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item">
            <h2>Modal Example2</h2>

            <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
            <button id="myBtn2" class="myBtn"><img src="img/bandlogos/Wormwoodlogo.jpg" alt="Wormwoods logga" width="300" height="200" /></button>

            <!-- The Modal -->
            <div id="myModal2" class="modal">

                <!-- Modal content -->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <span class="close">×</span>
                    <p>Some text in the Modal..2</p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Is there something wrong with how the code is used or have I thought wrong somewhere?

Edit:

When I removed the grid it worked at first but when I tried a JavaScript code example given as answer it didnt work so I thought fair enough I might have to change something else in the code but when I changed back it also stoped working.

Comment: This code, it's ugly and not reusable. Generate it dynamic, for example with "for" loop, etc.

Comment: Please provide a js fiddle link

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/347cxwr0/ I had problems adding it to the OP

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct, you can't close the modal if you click outside of it right?
Is the console showing any errors? Becouse in your `js` `event.target == modal` the `modal` is an array with all of your modals, not an object.
As it mentioned before me in the comment section, you should iterate through all of your modals and add an eventlistener dynamically.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName('modal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn");


// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

// Get opened modal
var openedModal = undefined;

function showModal(modal) {
  openedModal = modal;
  modal.style.display = 'block';
}
function hideModal(modal) {
  modal.style.display = 'none';
}
btn.forEach((element, index) => {
  element.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    showModal(modal[index]);
  }, false)
});
span.forEach((element, index) => {
  element.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    hideModal(modal[index]);
  }, false)
});

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it

window.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if (event.target != openedModal) {
        openedModal.style.display = "none";
    }
})
```

Comment: When I change it too your code the buttons for the modal dont work even when the grid is removed. I guess I would need the change the class and id for the diffrent modals would have to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Move the modals (not the buttons) outside the grid. Also, only add one modal at a time making sure each one works correctly. There were multiple id's that were the same and not made unique so that the references didn't work.

HTML:

```
<html lang="sv-se">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Artister</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/modalcss.css">
   </head>
      <body>
            <!-- The Modal -->
            <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                <!-- Modal content -->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <span class="close">×</span>
                    <p>Some text in the Modal..1</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <!-- The Modal -->
            <div id="myModal2" class="modal">
                <!-- Modal content -->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <span class="close">×</span>
                    <p>Some text in the Modal..2</p>
                </div>
            </div>  
            
            
            <div class="grid-container">
                <div class="grid-item">
                    <h2>Modal Example1</h2>
                    <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
                    <button id="myBtn" class="myBtn"><img src="img/bandlogos/Rammsteinlogo.png" alt="Rammsteins logga" width="300" height="200" /></button>
                </div>

                <div class="grid-item">
                    <h2>Modal Example2</h2>
                    <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
                    <button id="myBtn2" class="myBtn"><img src="img/bandlogos/Toollogo.png" alt="Tools logga" width="300" height="200" /></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="artister.html">1</a>|||<a href="2#">-></a>   
            <script src="js/modal.js"></script>
    </body>

</html >
```

Javascript:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName('modal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn[0].onclick = function () {
    modal[0].style.display = "block";
}

btn[1].onclick = function () {
    modal[1].style.display = "block";
}



// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span[0].onclick = function () {
    modal[0].style.display = "none";
}

span[1].onclick = function () {
    modal[1].style.display = "none";
}


// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: I used the grid to try to posistion the modals. It works when the grid is removed.