# Prevent background from scrolling when a modal is opened, but modal content is scrollable

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, modal-dialog, fullscreen

I have a modal box code that, when executed, doesn't fill up the whole height of the webpage, i.e., the main content can still be scrollable. What I want is:

1. My body (background) stops scrolling when the modal is opened, and
2. When the modal is opened, the modal content is scrollable.
3. Also, I want to use the modal box several times. That is I don't want to consider a single code to open several modal boxes.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<!--the same lines to make page long-->







<p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae expedita corrupti laudantium aperiam, doloremque explicabo ipsum earum dicta saepe delectus totam vitae ipsam doloribus et obcaecati facilis eius assumenda, cumque.</p>
    <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae expedita corrupti laudantium aperiam, doloremque explicabo ipsum earum dicta saepe delectus totam vitae ipsam doloribus et obcaecati facilis eius assumenda, cumque.</p>
    <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae expedita corrupti laudantium aperiam, doloremque explicabo ipsum earum dicta saepe delectus totam vitae ipsam doloribus et obcaecati facilis eius assumenda, cumque.</p>
    
    <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae expedita corrupti laudantium aperiam, doloremque explicabo ipsum earum dicta saepe delectus totam vitae ipsam doloribus et obcaecati facilis eius assumenda, cumque.</p>
    
    
    
    <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae expedita corrupti laudantium aperiam, doloremque explicabo ipsum earum dicta saepe delectus totam vitae ipsam doloribus et obcaecati facilis eius assumenda, cumque.</p>
    <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae expedita corrupti laudantium aperiam, doloremque explicabo ipsum earum dicta saepe delectus totam vitae ipsam doloribus et obcaecati facilis eius assumenda, cumque.</p>
    <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae expedita corrupti laudantium aperiam, doloremque explicabo ipsum earum dicta saepe delectus totam vitae ipsam doloribus et obcaecati facilis eius assumenda, cumque.</p>
    
    <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae expedita corrupti laudantium aperiam, doloremque explicabo ipsum earum dicta saepe delectus totam vitae ipsam doloribus et obcaecati facilis eius assumenda, cumque.</p>
    
     <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae expedita corrupti laudantium aperiam, doloremque explicabo ipsum earum dicta saepe delectus totam vitae ipsam doloribus et obcaecati facilis eius assumenda, cumque.</p>
    <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae expedita corrupti laudantium aperiam, doloremque explicabo ipsum earum dicta saepe delectus totam vitae ipsam doloribus et obcaecati facilis eius assumenda, cumque.</p>
    <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae expedita corrupti laudantium aperiam, doloremque explicabo ipsum earum dicta saepe delectus totam vitae ipsam doloribus et obcaecati facilis eius assumenda, cumque.</p>
    
    <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae expedita corrupti laudantium aperiam, doloremque explicabo ipsum earum dicta saepe delectus totam vitae ipsam doloribus et obcaecati facilis eius assumenda, cumque.</p>
    
     <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae expedita corrupti laudantium aperiam, doloremque explicabo ipsum earum dicta saepe delectus totam vitae ipsam doloribus et obcaecati facilis eius assumenda, cumque.</p>
    <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae expedita corrupti laudantium aperiam, doloremque explicabo ipsum earum dicta saepe delectus totam vitae ipsam doloribus et obcaecati facilis eius assumenda, cumque.</p>
    <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae expedita corrupti laudantium aperiam, doloremque explicabo ipsum earum dicta saepe delectus totam vitae ipsam doloribus et obcaecati facilis eius assumenda, cumque.</p>
    
    <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae expedita corrupti laudantium aperiam, doloremque explicabo ipsum earum dicta saepe delectus totam vitae ipsam doloribus et obcaecati facilis eius assumenda, cumque.</p>
    
     <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae expedita corrupti laudantium aperiam, doloremque explicabo ipsum earum dicta saepe delectus totam vitae ipsam doloribus et obcaecati facilis eius assumenda, cumque.</p>
    <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae expedita corrupti laudantium aperiam, doloremque explicabo ipsum earum dicta saepe delectus totam vitae ipsam doloribus et obcaecati facilis eius assumenda, cumque.</p>
    <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae expedita corrupti laudantium aperiam, doloremque explicabo ipsum earum dicta saepe delectus totam vitae ipsam doloribus et obcaecati facilis eius assumenda, cumque.</p>
    
    <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae expedita corrupti laudantium aperiam, doloremque explicabo ipsum earum dicta saepe delectus totam vitae ipsam doloribus et obcaecati facilis eius assumenda, cumque.</p>
    
    
     <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae expedita corrupti laudantium aperiam, doloremque explicabo ipsum earum dicta saepe delectus totam vitae ipsam doloribus et obcaecati facilis eius assumenda, cumque.</p>
    <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae expedita corrupti laudantium aperiam, doloremque explicabo ipsum earum dicta saepe delectus totam vitae ipsam doloribus et obcaecati facilis eius assumenda, cumque.</p>
    <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae expedita corrupti laudantium aperiam, doloremque explicabo ipsum earum dicta saepe delectus totam vitae ipsam doloribus et obcaecati facilis eius assumenda, cumque.</p>
    
    <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae expedita corrupti laudantium aperiam, doloremque explicabo ipsum earum dicta saepe delectus totam vitae ipsam doloribus et obcaecati facilis eius assumenda, cumque.</p>
    
    
    
     <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae expedita corrupti laudantium aperiam, doloremque explicabo ipsum earum dicta saepe delectus totam vitae ipsam doloribus et obcaecati facilis eius assumenda, cumque.</p>
    <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae expedita corrupti laudantium aperiam, doloremque explicabo ipsum earum dicta saepe delectus totam vitae ipsam doloribus et obcaecati facilis eius assumenda, cumque.</p>
    <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae expedita corrupti laudantium aperiam, doloremque explicabo ipsum earum dicta saepe delectus totam vitae ipsam doloribus et obcaecati facilis eius assumenda, cumque.</p>
    
    <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae expedita corrupti laudantium aperiam, doloremque explicabo ipsum earum dicta saepe delectus totam vitae ipsam doloribus et obcaecati facilis eius assumenda, cumque.</p>
    
     <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae expedita corrupti laudantium aperiam, doloremque explicabo ipsum earum dicta saepe delectus totam vitae ipsam doloribus et obcaecati facilis eius assumenda, cumque.</p>
    <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae expedita corrupti laudantium aperiam, doloremque explicabo ipsum earum dicta saepe delectus totam vitae ipsam doloribus et obcaecati facilis eius assumenda, cumque.</p>
    <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae expedita corrupti laudantium aperiam, doloremque explicabo ipsum earum dicta saepe delectus totam vitae ipsam doloribus et obcaecati facilis eius assumenda, cumque.</p>
    
    <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae expedita corrupti laudantium aperiam, doloremque explicabo ipsum earum dicta saepe delectus totam vitae ipsam doloribus et obcaecati facilis eius assumenda, cumque.</p>
    
    
    
    
    
    
    <!--modal html-->
    
    
    <div id="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="header">
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="copy">
      <p>Modal Body</p>
      <a href="#">Close Link</a> </div>
  </div>
  <!--<div class="overlay"></div>-->
</div>

<a class="button" href="#modal">
  Launch A Modal
</a>
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
<style>
body,
html{
  margin: 0;
}
.button {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  margin: 40px 0 0 40px; 
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}
.button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  color: whitesmoke;
}
#modal {
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  background: #1D1F20;
}

#modal:target {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  visibility: visible
}

#modal .header,
#modal .footer {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1ABC9C;
  border-radius: 0;
}

#modal .footer {
  border: none;
}

#modal h2 {
  margin: 0;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

#modal .btn {
  float: right
}

#modal .copy,
#modal .header,
#modal .footer {
  padding: 10px;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
  color: #fff;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#modal .copy {
  background: #1D1F20;
}

#modal .overlay {
  background-color: #000;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10
}

.copy a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background-color: none;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.copy a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}
</style>
```

---

```
// Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.querySelectorAll("button.modal-button");

    // All page modals
    var modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
    for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
     btn[i].onclick = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        modal = document.querySelector(e.target.getAttribute("href"));
        modal.style.display = "block";
     }
    }

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
     spans[i].onclick = function() {
        for (var index in modals) {
          if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined') modals[index].style.display = "none";    
        }
     }
    }

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target.classList.contains('modal')) {
         for (var index in modals) {
          if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined') modals[index].style.display = "none";    
         }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You didn't provide javascript code, but basically as you show the modal (and its overlay) you should also add a class to the body that makes it `overflow:hidden` until the modal is closed then remove that class from body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can you use this

```
function disable(){
document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';}


function enable(){
document.body.style.overflow = 'scroll';}



function disableScrolling() {
disable();}


function enableScrolling() {
enable();}
```

and in the anchor tag for opening the model use this onclick='return disableScrolling()

example

```
<a class="button" href="#modal"  onclick='return disableScrolling()'>Launch A Modal</a>
```

and for closing the model use this

```
<a href="#" onclick='return enableScrolling()'>Close Link</a>
```

and in the model content div use this

```
style="overflow-y: scroll; height:400px;"
```

Comment: Could you please answer the third question? (the third question was from the beginning) I have added the javascript I am trying to use to solve problem 3. Thanks in advance

Comment: could you please explain more to understand what you want to do

Comment: I want to open several modal boxes using the same CSS with   ```<div id="modal1">, <div id="modal2">```, etc..... with corresponding ```<a class="button" href="#modal1"  onclick='return disableScrolling()'>Launch A Modal</a>```, ```<a class="button" href="#modal2"  onclick='return disableScrolling()'>Launch A Modal</a>```, etc....

Comment: so you want if a user clicks on the launch a model it opens several model boxes in the same time ?

Comment: No. for each open button I have exactly one modal box, like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40645236/13805201

Comment: check answer number two please

Comment: Hi, I have a new question: I can use the browser back-arrow or mobile back-key to close the modal, but after doing this, I can't scroll through the background. Could you help me? See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73037466/enable-scrolling-the-background-when-the-modal-is-closed-using-the-back-key-inst

Answer (score 1):

for the third question you can use this
for example

```
<div id="modal2" class="model">
```

you will add class= "model"
then change the id with model1 or model2 or model3 ..etc
then open the CSS file using vscode and search for #model then replace all with ".model"

and use this as example

```
      <a class="stopb" href="#modal2"  onclick='return disableScrolling()'>
  Launch A Modal2
  </a>
```

you have to change the href to the id of the model

Comment: Hi, I have a new question: I can use the browser back-arrow or mobile back-key to close the modal, but after doing this, I can't scroll through the background. Could you help me? See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73037466/enable-scrolling-the-background-when-the-modal-is-closed-using-the-back-key-inst